# Requesting examples of sys_fork in nasm

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I'm trying to run bzip and have it return control to the calling function from inside a nasm-coded assembly program (under linux). I apparently need to use a combination of the sys_fork and sys_execve system calls to achive this. After much searching, I found an example of how to use sys_execve, however I can't find an example of how to use sys_fork. Any help with my request will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is limited, but as I recall `sys_fork` is easy. "Just do it" - no parameters. At this point, you're "in two places at once". If `eax` is zero, you're the child - do `sys_execve` on bzip. If `eax` is non-zero (and non-negative!), you're the parent and `eax` is your PID. Do a `sys_waitpid` on that PID. As I recall, this returns the exit status of bzip shifted left 8 bytes - `sys_execve` itself never returns.

I have a crude example that runs an editor, nasm, and ld (all on a hard-coded "hello.asm"). Longish to post, but I can make it available some way if you need it. I found getting the correct parameters to `sys_execve` the hardest part, as I recall.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input; it's greatly appreciated. If it's not too much trouble, I'll take you up on your offer of sample code. Thanks again!